# How to use hunspell package to suggest correct words in a column in R?

Tags: r, spell-checking, hunspell

I'm currently working with a large data frame containing lots of text in each row and would like to effectively identify and replace misspelled words in each sentence with the `hunspell` package. I was able to identify the misspelled words, but can't figure out how to do `hunspell_suggest` on a list.

Here is an example of the data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame("Index" = 1:7, "Text" = c("A complec sentence joins an independet",
                                            "Mary and Samantha arived at the bus staton before noon",
                                            "I did not see thm at the station in the mrning",
                                            "The participnts read 60 sentences in radom order",
                                            "how to fix mispelled words in R languge",
                                            "today is Tuesday",
                                            "bing sports quiz"))
```

I converted the text column into character and used `hunspell` to identify the misspelled words within each row.

```
library(hunspell)
df1$Text <- as.character(df1$Text)
df1$word_check <- hunspell(df1$Text)
```

I tried

```
df1$suggest <- hunspell_suggest(df1$word_check)
```

but it keeps giving this error:

```
Error in hunspell_suggest(df1$word_check) : 
  is.character(words) is not TRUE
```

I'm new to this so I'm not exactly sure how does the suggest column using `hunspell_suggest` function would turn out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your intermediate steps. The output of `df1$word_check` is as follows:

```
List of 5
 $ : chr [1:2] "complec" "independet"
 $ : chr [1:2] "arived" "staton"
 $ : chr [1:2] "thm" "mrning"
 $ : chr [1:2] "participnts" "radom"
 $ : chr [1:2] "mispelled" "languge"
```

which is of type `list`. If you did `lapply(df1$word_check, hunspell_suggest)` you can get the suggestions.

**EDIT**

I decided to go into more detail on this question as I have not seen any easy alternative. This is what I have come up with:

```
cleantext = function(x){

  sapply(1:length(x),function(y){
    bad = hunspell(x[y])[[1]]
    good = unlist(lapply(hunspell_suggest(bad),`[[`,1))

    if (length(bad)){
      for (i in 1:length(bad)){
        x[y] <<- gsub(bad[i],good[i],x[y])
      }}})
  x
}
```

Although there probably is a more elegant way of doing it, this function returns a vector of character strings corrected as such:

```
> df1$Text
[1] "A complec sentence joins an independet"                
[2] "Mary and Samantha arived at the bus staton before noon"
[3] "I did not see thm at the station in the mrning"        
[4] "The participnts read 60 sentences in radom order"      
[5] "how to fix mispelled words in R languge"               
[6] "today is Tuesday"                                      
[7] "bing sports quiz" 

> cleantext(df1$Text)
[1] "A complex sentence joins an independent"               
[2] "Mary and Samantha rived at the bus station before noon"
[3] "I did not see them at the station in the morning"      
[4] "The participants read 60 sentences in radon order"     
[5] "how to fix misspelled words in R language"             
[6] "today is Tuesday"                                      
[7] "bung sports quiz"
```

Watch out, as this returns the first suggestion given by `hunspell` - which may or may not be correct.

Comment: I see, that works for the suggestion part. Thank you. Would you happen to know how to replace the misspelled words with the first suggestion of each word then?

Comment: this line returns an error if the list of suggestions are emtpy. good = unlist(lapply(hunspell_suggest(bad),`[[`,1))